# CTE based sequence generation with HSQLDB

Tags: sql, sequence, hsqldb, common-table-expression

I am using a recursive common table expression to fetch a batch of sequence number. The following query works with Postgres, SQL Server and H2 (minus the `VALUES` part).

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n, level_num) AS (
    SELECT next value for seq_parent_id as n,
           1 as level_num
      FROM (VALUES(0))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT next value for seq_parent_id as n,
           level_num + 1 as level_num
      FROM t
     WHERE level_num < ?)
SELECT n FROM t
```

However with HSQLDB 2.4.0 I get the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: T
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    ... 
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: T
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSetOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSubqueryTableBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableNamedSubqueryBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
```

This specific use case could also be solved with a combination of `UNNEST` and `SEQUENCE_ARRAY` but I'd like to avoid having to introduce an HSQLDB specific code path.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with the simplest form of the recursive query without use of sequences and with hard-coded limit and then gradually add extra bits to it.

Based on the example in the docs [With Clause and Recursive Queries](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_with_clause) the syntax should look like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
t(level_num)
AS
(
    VALUES(1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        level_num + 1
    FROM t
    WHERE level_num < 10
)
SELECT level_num 
FROM t
;
```

By the way, the docs say:

> HyperSQL limits recursion to 265 rounds. If this is exceeded, an error
>   is raised.

I'd try the simplest query, like the one above, make sure that it works, then try it with, say, `1000` instead of `10` and see what error it returns. If it is the same error that you had originally, then you found the reason.

---

A side note: I'd use a permanent table of numbers instead of generating them on the fly recursively for the task of this kind. We have a table with 100K numbers in our system. It is simple and would work in any DBMS. Populate it once and use as needed. I know that in SQL Server recursive query is significantly slower (in this kind of task), I don't know about HyperSQL though. Also, the limit of recursion depth to just 265 is rather harsh. Most likely, with such low limit on the recursion depth it would be impossible to detect any difference in performance. But, again, is 265 numbers enough for your purposes?

Comment: If I execute your code the query never returns but burns a lot of CPU. Does the query run for you?

I'm fine with a recursion limit of 265 rounds, I don't expect users to use more than 100 (they, I know). It's "frameworky" code so I don't want to have to impose a numbers table on users.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have HSQLDB at hand to try. I wrote it looking only at the docs. The main point still holds. I would try to make the simplest possible recursive query and then add extra bits to it one by one. Such as, increasing the number of iterations, then adding use of sequences.

Comment: I agree, I tried your code, I don't see how I could simplify it any further and it fails without an error message (just burning CPU). So I'm a bit at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB has an issue with the 'UNION ALL'. In above referred example "With Clause and Recursive Queries" there is no 'UNION ALL', but only 'UNION' (note that documentation might be changed).
In [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1343/) there is some discussion about it. But at the moment I cannot get a working recursive statement in HSQLDB that uses UNION ALL.

So use UNION for HSQLDB v 2.3.2+

---

Fred Toussi commented on above thread. In version 2.5.1 and upwards UNION ALL should behave as expected.